# unable to retrieve the new primary key from the database

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have a gaming project. Each game dynamically generates a unique id. I retrieve the primary key from the database using the id by using the where clause. Once the game is over the user can play the game again. Second time he plays the game a new unique id is generated. Now when i try to retrieve the new primary key by specifying the new id, instead of getting the new primary key i am getting the older primary key. what may be the reason for this strange behavior?

```
public long getPrimaryKey(String id) 
{ 
    Query q = getSession().createQuery("FROM Game_Answers g where g.gameid= '"+id+"' "); 
    Game_Answers ga=(Game_Answers)q.uniqueResult(); 
    return ga.getId(); 
}
```

Comment: We need lots more info. Code for  "retrieve the primary key from the database using the id by using the where" and example of 2 seperate runs of the game showing the issue, would be a start

Comment: public long getPrimaryKey(String id) {
  
  Query q = getSession().createQuery("FROM Game_Answers g where g.gameid= '"+id+"' ");
  Game_Answers ga=(Game_Answers)q.uniqueResult();
  return ga.getId();
 }

Comment: Please add that to the question, and format properly

Comment: Might also need where the "Unique ID" is assigned to the "Primary key" or vice versa